# Node.js unable to find a unique ID for a guest visiting my web/app

Tags: node.js

I want to get the user's IP or unique device ID so I can allow / disallow him to register based on history of tries he did.

Therefore: a guest visits my app.
This guest register.
I want to block him for register again at-least for two days.
But I do not how to do to this because he is guest.

OR, a guest ask for a SMS verification.
I want to allow him do that only 5 times a day.

I have searched tons of searches in Google on how to get a user's IP, but it did not work and I did not success finding his IP - **seems too complicated or unreachable.**

I have tried to use the UUID plugin by npm (GitHub repo) but this gave the same UUID for all visitors (probably it gave the UUID of the server or something).

I need an efficient way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that, you're using `express` framework.

Add the npm module `express-session` in your server.js file like,

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret : 'yourSecretPassPhrase',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie : {
      maxAge : 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2 //for two days(in millisec)
    }
  })
);
```

Thereafter, a session object is inserted in every request!

```
app.get('/setUser', function(request, response){
        request.session.allowUser = true;      //creates user session
    })
);

app.get('/removeUser', function(request, response){
        del request.session.allowUser;      //deletes user session
    })
);

app.get('/checkUser', function(request, response){
        if(request.session.allowUser){
            //your code for existing or returning user
        }else{
            //your code for new user or session expired user
        }
    })
);
```

express-session takes care of cookie management for you.

For more details check npm doc here https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sessions.

You could get user's ip address from request object like

```
const clientIp = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.connection.remoteAddress;
```

But most probably client user will use dynamic ip. So, I would recommend you to use the `express-session` npm module, which tracks user using cookie rather than ip address

Comment: And about session solution you provided: I was just about to ask another question about this, but here it is :)]